# How do I use use the tfidf-calculating functions in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, tf-idf

I want to use the `TfidfVectorizer` and associated functions from scikit-learn in order to perform document classification, but I am a little puzzled on its use (and none of the other questions I've searched dealt with proper data formatting).

Currently, my training data is organized in the following way:

1. Get single text from corpus.
2. Normalize, tokenize (using nltk PunktWordTokenizer), stem (using nltk SnowballStemmer)
3. Filter out low-length and low-occurrence words that are left
4. Label the corresponding text

After the above is done, a single text looks as follows (values here are random but correspond to the count / number of occurrences of each term ):

```
text = ({"has": 5.0, "love": 12.0, ...}, "Relationships")
```

Whereas the full corpus looks something like this at the end:

```
corpus = [({"has": 5.0, "love": 12.0, ...}, "Relationships"),
          ({"game": 9, "play": 9.0, ...}, "Games"),
          ...,
         ]
```

How would I feed this data into `TfidfVectorizer()`? Do I have to supply just the content (as dictionaries? as lists?) as it is above, or just the content without the counts? When do I supply the labels? I wouldn't mind refactoring my data completely if need be.

The documentation with regard to this specific function is unfortunately a little sparse with examples with regard to formatting.

Comment: what are your numeric values?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by that, which makes me think I may have a fundamental misunderstanding as to how tfidf operates. Could you please explain?

Comment: Your original text has only words, how do you get to the numbers you show there(the values of your dicts)?

Comment: Oh, my apologies. The numeric values are counts for each word (so basically, term frequency for a given document). I should have made that clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you would use `TfidfVectorizer`([look here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html) for more details)

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
>>> corpus = ['This is the first document.',
              'This is the second second document.',
              'And the third one.',
              'Is this the first document?']
>>> vect = TfidfVectorizer()
>>> X = vect.fit_transform(corpus)
>>> X.todense()

matrix([[ 0.        ,  0.43877674,  0.54197657,  0.43877674,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.35872874,  0.        ,  0.43877674],
        [ 0.        ,  0.27230147,  0.        ,  0.27230147,  0.        ,
          0.85322574,  0.22262429,  0.        ,  0.27230147],
        [ 0.55280532,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.55280532,
          0.        ,  0.28847675,  0.55280532,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.43877674,  0.54197657,  0.43877674,  0.        ,
          0.        ,  0.35872874,  0.        ,  0.43877674]])
```

This is the numeric representation of your text corpus. Now to fit a model that maps documents to your labels, start by putting them in a target variable, the length of the labels should match the number of documents in the corpus:

```
>>> y = ['Relationships', 'Games', ...]
```

Now you can fit any model, for example:

```
>>> from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
>>> model = SGDClassifier()
>>> model.fit(X, y)
```

Now you have a fitted model that you can evaluate on new data. To predict repeat the same process for the new corpus or texts. Note that I am using the same vectorizer `vect` as before:

```
X_pred = vect.transform(['My new document'])
y_pred = model.predict(X_pred)
```

If you want to use a custom tokenizer use:

```
vect = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=your_custom_tokenizer_function)
```

Comment: The ordering of the labels in `y` must correspond to the ordering of the documents in the corpus, correct? Also, should the `corpus` I provide to `fit_transform` contain the *non*-preprocessed data or the preprocessed data?

Comment: yes, same order. TfidfVectorizer preprocesses and tokenizes the input but you can override that providing custom functions. You can pass a list of docs(strings) like in my example, but also a filename, take a look at [the docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer).